# Why I can't login to admin using client?

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-admin, python-unittest

I try to test my custom action. But when I go to admin page using `client` I get error `<HttpResponseRedirect status_code=302, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="/admin/login/?next=/admin/donation/donation/">`

```
class ExportToExcelTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.user = UserFactory()

    def test_export_to_excel(self) -> None:
        data = {'action': 'export_to_excel'}
        change_url = '/admin/donation/donation/'
        self.user.is_staff = True
        self.user.is_superuser = True
        self.user.save()
        self.client.login(username=self.user.username, password=self.user.password)
        response = self.client.post(change_url, data)
        print(response)   #<HttpResponseRedirect status_code=302, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="/admin/login/?next=/admin/donation/donation/">
```

Comment: What’s the error you get?

Comment: I get redirect to `/admin/login/?` page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't log in with `self.user.password` - that is the *hashed* password for the user, not the password they would use to log in - hence your login is failing (you can verify this by checking the return value of `login()` - it will be `False`).

Since you're not actually testing authentication here, you should just use [`force_login`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.force_login) instead:

```
def test_export_to_excel(self) -> None:
    data = {'action': 'export_to_excel'}
    change_url = '/admin/donation/donation/'
    self.user.is_staff = True
    self.user.is_superuser = True
    self.user.save()
    self.client.force_login(self.user)
    response = self.client.post(change_url, data)
```